# Get a phone number in a telegram through BotFramework

Tags: .net, botframework, telegram-bot

I want to get a phone number in a telegram through BotFramework. About it is written here https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/azure/bot-service/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-channeldata?view=azure-bot-service-3.0#create-a-telegram - message 
But I can not understand how to write it in code. Interested in the sendContact method. I would be grateful for the help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can i get a phone number by user id via Telegram Bot API?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33035709/can-i-get-a-phone-number-by-user-id-via-telegram-bot-api)

Comment: This is not possible